# Appending in FlatBuffer

Tags: flatbuffers

We already are using a flatbuffer with a similar scheme

```
namespace potter;

union Magic { Weapon, Wand }

table Weapon {
   name:string;     
   power:int; 
}

table Wand {
   make:string;
   animal:string;
}

table MagicHolder {   
    name:string;   
    age:int;    
    magic:Magic; 
}

root_type MagicHolder;
```

Now,  if we want to add two things.

1. `level:string` in the `MagicHolder`
2. Under the `Wand` a `key:value` type, where `key:string`, and `value` can be either `string or int or float or bool`

What I’m trying is

```
table MagicHolder {   
    name:string;   
    age:int; 
    level:string; /*new addition*/  
    magic:Magic; 
}

table KeyValue {
   key:string;  
   vint:int; 
   vfloat:float; 
   vbool:bool; 
   vstring:string;
   vtype:string; /* since I cannot differentiate between bool set or not, trying to store type here */
}

table Wand {
   make:string;
   animal:string;
   kv:KeyValue;  
}
```

Is this the best approach? What would be the pros/cons.. Any other recommended ways to do this new additions more efficiently

Comment: Level string needs to be at the end of table. We can't evolve schema safely by inserting fields in between.

Comment: I also thought so.. however, the last value is of type Magic, which is a union.. so could `level` still be after a union (which is of different type)

Comment: Can create a union of all the value types...   Kept in KeyValue

Comment: Yes you may and should add new entries (union or not) at the end of table.